# MS Teams Automation : Make a call from MS Teams

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, microsoft-teams

I need to automate Dial a call from MS teams to 3rd party IP phone. I am searching for APIs to automate the same. I tried to use Gaph API but not able to generate accees token.
Can any one help here please.

Thank you so much.

Regards,
-kranti

Comment: There doesn't seems to be any API available to automate dial a call from MS teams to 3rd party IP phone.
You can suggest this feature on https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seems to be any API available to automate dial a call from MS teams to 3rd party IP phone.

You can suggest this feature on [Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)